# InterlockedCompareExchange@12 could not be located in DLL SDL2_ttf.dll

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks, sdl-2

I have been having this issue for a little while now but i need to fix it. I am working on a Frogger game using SDL2. To make the score board i am trying to use SDL2_ttf. However i run into this error everytime i try to Initialize SDL_ttf using TTF_Init();

Here is the error i get:

[image: Error Message]

Now i have already looked at the other postings that are similar to this and most suggest that i move the DLL files into the debug folder(Bin\Debug) of my program. This has not worked for me. I have tried re downloading SDL2_ttf.dll from [Here](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/).

Im not sure exactly what is causing this error but here are some other screenshots that might prove helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am running Windows 8.1 and i am using Code::Blocks as the IDE.

I hope someone out there might be able to help me.

If you need any additional information I will happily provide it.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Put all .dll files into Debug directory, if doesn't work, put in  project folder.